# How do I write this in EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a two collection one is Category and the other is Blog
while looping out the category, i want to get the numbers of post such category have in my Blog collection, using the category field in blog collection
I was able to have this output on console with the code below, but how do I render it in ejs to have this result beneath?

Business 4

Sport 2

Religion 1

But how do I render it in ejs to look like this

I did this in my routes with the code below

```
app.get('/articles/play', async (req, res) => {
    const category = await catModel.find()
    category.forEach(async cat => {
        // console.log(cat.catname)
        const countIt = await blogModel.countDocuments({category: cat.catname})
        console.log(cat.catname, countIt)
    })

})
```

Comment: Have no time to answer your question completely, but have a look at this question which demonstrates how to iterate with async functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form a array of json where you push this data and pass this array to ejs to blindly render, like below

```
 app.get('/articles/play', async (req, res) => {
        const category = await catModel.find();
        const ejsArr = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
            const countIt = await blogModel.countDocuments({category: category[i].catname});
            ejsArr.push({name:cat.catname, count:countIt});    
        }
        console.log(ejsArr)
        res.render('article', ejsArr);    
});
```

Comment: Please can you share light on how i will output the ejsArr in ejs templates? Thanks.

Comment: once this ejsArr is formed, in your ejs just loop through this array and use html css to design it, (or simply print it). (I assume you know ejs else refer this http://tanmaysarkar.com/array-with-ejs-template-in-nodejs/)

Comment: I loop through the ejsArr on my view and is showing empty, but when i console.log(ejsArr) i have this output   [ { name: 'Business', count: 4 } ]
[ { name: 'Business', count: 4 }, { name: 'Sport', count: 2 } ]
[
  { name: 'Business', count: 4 },
  { name: 'Sport', count: 2 },
  { name: 'Religion', count: 1 }
]

Comment: there is something wrong here, why your array has repeated values, are you have loops before sample code?

Comment: console log before res.render('article', ejsArr); and share that data

Comment: Console.log(ejsArr) return an empty array

Comment: from where did you got previous log then?

Comment: inside the loop

Comment: I have update answer with for loop, it was empty because it had async code and was not waiting for foreach to complete